# Questions about bikes and astronomy

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

Where can I ask questions about these two topics:

- Motorbikes [should I ask it on Bicycles SE?]
- Astronomy

Comment: Why the downvotes? +1 for getting advice and not just going and posting these on StackOverflow (or other unrelated sites)!

Comment: @Mehrdad I downvoted. I thought the OP showed a lack of effort with this question. I can't remember when (or if) I've downvoted for that reason before, but I thought this instance was so bad that it went beyond laziness and into rudeness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to mean "motorcycles". In that case there was a [proposal which has been closed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6788/motorcycles). It never seems to have come out of the commitment phase.  However, it's been reopened as [Motorcycling](http://goo.gl/ij3AO) to give that community a second chance.

However, as suggested by @random, the Mechanics SE seems to house [some questions tagged "motorcycle"](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorcycle). So perhaps have a look there.

The [bicycles SE](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/) is not on-topic for questions about motorcycles it seems.

A proposal and beta for an [Astronomy SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51/astronomy) didn't make it. It was closed in public beta. It seems the number of visits and questions per day was not sufficient for it to survive. As it says on that page, you can [download the dump here](http://sstatic.net/area51/datadumps/052012%20Astronomy.zip) And it has been merged into the [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/), so perhaps you can try your luck there. I don't participate though, so check the faq first.

Comment: is there any way to browse the closed Astronomy section ?

Comment: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorcycle

Comment: @random Added that to my answer if you don't mind. Thanks.

Comment: In response to the closure of Motorcycles and promise that a [new proposal won't be closed as a dup](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/5798/29959), I've reopened a [Motorcycling proposal](http://goo.gl/ij3AO) to give this community a second chance.

Answer (score 1):

For bicycle questions that is [Bicycles](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com), which is described as the site for, "people who build and repair bicycles, people who train cycling, or commute on bicycles." If your question fall under one of those categories, it should be welcome, if it is not too broad, or constructive.

For astronomy questions, the proposal didn't graduate, and the site has been merged with [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

For motorcycles questions, there is [Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com), which is described as, "for mechanics and DIY-enthusiast owners of cars, trucks, and motorcycles."
There was also a [Motorcycles](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6788/motorcycles) proposal, but it has never reached the beta phase.
I can also find a [Off Roading](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40121/off-roading) proposal, which is described as, "Proposed Q&A site for those who are interested in driving vehicles or cycling off road in a fun, secure and safe manner."

Comment: I'm asking about motorbike !

Comment: You didn't say motorbikes, you said bikes.

Comment: @Sourav You said _bikes_, which could mean _bicycles_, or _motorcycles_. If you meant motorcycles, and exclusively motorcycles, you should say _motorcycles_. You asked if you should ask bike questions on Bicycles, and I replied for which cases bicycles.stackexchange.com should be used.